# I want a code to rep a big matrix in row wise

Tags: matrices, syntax, horizontal

```
\begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \big| & \big| & \cdots & \big| \\
        x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_{m-1} \\
        \big| & \big| & \cdots & \big| \\       
    \end{bmatrix} \hspace {0.1cm} \in X ,
    \label{x1}
\end{align}
```

The above code produces a matrix with Xs in the column but I want a code to make the Xs in row (row-wise rep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `\mdash` (matrix dash) command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mdash}{\mathinner{\relbar\joinrel\relbar\joinrel\relbar}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mdash & x_1 & \mdash \\
  \mdash & x_2 & \mdash \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  \mdash & x_{m-1} & \mdash
\end{bmatrix} \in X ,
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explicit `\hspace` commands are generally out of place in math formulas (but in some cases they're useful).

Don't use `align` for single line displays. If you want an equation number, use `equation`.

Comment: This works, thank you so much @egreg